# doctrine-mongoDB - ContextErrorException: Warning: Illegal offset

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.3, doctrine-odm

I had made Id of document as MongoBinData object using annotation as

```
namespace  Profile\UserBundle\Document;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;

/**
 * User Document 
 *  
 *@MongoDB\Document(
 *  collection="Users",
 *  repositoryClass = "Profile\UserBundle\Document\UsersRepository"
 * )
 * 
 * @author ahmedhamdy
 */
class Users {

    /**
     * 
     * @var bin_uuid
     * 
     * @MongoDB\Id(strategy = "UUID") 
     * 
     */
    protected $id;


    /**
     *
     * @var string 
     * 
     * @MongoDB\Field(type = "string",name = "Email")
     * 
     */
    protected $email;    
//...
```

when i try to get object from MongoDB By email like :

```
    $dm = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager();

   $user = $dm->getRepository('ProfileUserBundle:Users')->findOneBy(array(

                        'email' => 'xxxx@hotmail.com',
                ));
   var_dump($user);
```

then throw an Exception :

```
ContextErrorException: Warning: Illegal offset type in /var/www/xxxxx/vendor/doctrine/mongodb-odm/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/UnitOfWork.php line 1544
```

- How to work with MongoBinData object ???
- how to insert new Users object with id from type MongoBinData object ??
- is there any way to convert MongoBinData object to string ??

Answer (score 1):

This feature is currently being worked on in [PR #444](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/pull/444). The test cases introduced in that PR will also demonstrate how to use special types for an identifier field until we get a chance to write up new examples in the documentation.

Regarding conversion of MongoBinData to a string value, you should access the `$bin` property instead of using [MongoBinData::__toString()](http://php.net/manual/en/mongobindata.tostring.php). The `__toString()` method, which is also invoked when casting MongoBinData to a string, will return `"<Mongo Binary Data>"` regardless of the binary data stored within.

Comment: Warning: Illegal offset is not happen again to me when I  used ```@MongoDB\Id(type="bin_uuid")``` instead of ```@MongoDB\Id(strategy = "UUID")```
**BUT** now i can`t get data from fields with with annotation ```@MongoDB\EmbedOne``` , ```@MongoDB\EmbedMany``` and ```@MongoDB\ReferenceOne``` 
all this fields appear as array with size zero

Comment: I want to make sure you're not confusing the UUID strategy, which creates strings, with the binary type. The UUID binary data subtype doesn't have any practical purpose in ODM, and if you're storing printable characters in a binary-mapped field, you're better off just using the string type. Regarding the other issue you're facing, let's follow up in [#751](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/issues/751).